# Listing dropped elements in R

Tags: r, list

I had a list of data with each element of the list being a matrix. Something like:

```
a <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(1/0, 3)), nrow = 3)
b <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(2, 3)), nrow = 3)
c <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(3, 3)), nrow = 3)

RUNS.original <- list(a,b,c)
```

I needed to convert it into a list without any list elements that contained `Inf` (i.e., I needed `RUNS.new <- list(b,c)`).

I created `RUNS.new` using:

```
RUNS.new <- RUNS.original[sapply(RUNS.original, function(x) all(is.finite(x)))]
```

Now, I have a separate list, `SUMMARIES.original`, that is composed of vectors of aggregated data that correspond to `RUNS.original` (i.e., the ith element or `SUMMARIES.original` was generated from the ith element of `RUNS.orignal`).

So, `SUMMARIES.original` looks something like this:

```
a <- sum(RUNS.original[[1]])
b <- sum(RUNS.original[[2]])
c <- sum(RUNS.original[[3]])
SUMMARIES.original <- list(a,b,c)
```

What I need to get to is a list of the data from `SUMMARIES.original` that has the elements removed from `RUNS.original` to create `RUNS.new` removed as well (i.e., I need `SUMMARIES.new <- list(b,c)` since `a` was removed from `RUNS.original`.

Comment: `SUMMARIES.new <- SUMMARIES.original[sapply(RUNS.original, function(x) all(is.finite(x)))]`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks. Two days from finishing a dissertation, and I can't think to save my life.